# How to Create Entry form easily

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, forms, angular-material

#### Qusetion:

What is the best tool for creating Entry forms Tools should be easy to use with most drag and drop functionality and less coding?

#### Current Use:

I am using Angular Material library, Node js & Mongo Db but it takes a good time to build forms.

*can anyone please suggest the some shortest way or tools which I used to create a form?*

Answer (score 0):

There is no drag and drop tool except.
Bootstrap, just copy and paste.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/